# Unable to open android app from browser

Tags: android, android-browser

I have seen lot of solution for opening app from browser but don't know where I am doing wrong. Actually I need to open my app (if available on user device) via a link. User will get the link via sms and when he click on that link my java script code will look for that particular app in user device (via scheme) . The below code is working perfectly in IOS but not in android. Please help.

My web link code which try to open app from browser:

var appStoreURL = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/workout-trainer/id395686735?mt=8";

```
    //Check is device is iOS
    var iOS = (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false);
    var appiOSUrlScheme = "myappscheme://" + window.location.search;

   //alert(appUrlScheme);

    var weblink="https://example/Home.net"

    var AndroidStoreURL = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/workout-trainer/id395686735?mt=8";

    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
    var appAndroidUrlScheme = " myappscheme://" + window.location.search; ;


    if (iOS) {
        //If the app is not installed the script will wait for 2sec and redirect to web.
        alert(appiOSUrlScheme);
        var loadedAt = +new Date;
        setTimeout(
               function () {
                   if (+new Date - loadedAt < 2000) {
                       window.location = appStoreURL;
                   }
               }
               , 25);
        //Try launching the app using URL schemes
        window.open(appiOSUrlScheme, "_self");
    }
    else if (isAndroid) {
        alert(appAndroidUrlScheme);
        //If the app is not installed the script will wait for 2sec and redirect to web.
        var loadedAt = +new Date;
        setTimeout(
               function () {
                   if (+new Date - loadedAt < 2000) {
                       window.location = AndroidStoreURL;
                   }
               }
               , 25);
        //Try launching the app using URL schemes
               window.open(appAndroidUrlScheme, "_self");
    }
    else {
        //Launch the website
        window.location = weblink;
    }

</script>
```

Android Mainfest Code :

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VIEW" />

            <data
        android:pathPrefix="/Home"
        android:scheme="myappscheme" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: android:scheme="myappscheme" should be according to your app , like www.google.com

Comment: Thanks Qamar for quick response .. Just need to correct my self : You mean I need to change it in javascript file : var appAndroidUrlScheme = " myappscheme://"  like  var appAndroidUrlScheme ="www.example.com" and in my manifest also like :   android:scheme="www.example.com"

Comment: Please help me on this as I got stucked and have tried almost all possible solution.. waiting for response...

Comment: @sharma.mahesh you should add host in data tag without that it wont open your app

Comment: Thanks allDroid.. it is working after adding host...